# List only used jars

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have Maven projects which I can build with these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

There are a lot of jars into these dependencies and I would like to use on the necessary. How I can list which jars are only needed for the build?

Comment: Are you asking with transitive dependency is really needed? Or which direct dependency is really needed?

Comment: Yes, I want to know which direct dependency is really needed.

Comment: Are you looking for `mvn dependency:analyze`?

Comment: I don't know, what I can do with it?

Comment: You can analyze dependencies with it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to you question is that there is no easy way to do what you are asking.  In maven you declare for your package all the dependencies that the code inside your package will ever need in all scenarios.  In this case if your using only a specific part of the wildfly-embedded package, and that part that you are using only depends on a subset of the package's declared dependencies then Maven has no way of knowing this.

One approach you could take is to simply look at the declared dependencies of those artifacts, exclude one of them, and then run your test suite.  Assuming you have a comprehensive test suite if the tests past then you can reasonably assume that the dependency you excluded was not required by any of the parts of the library you utilized.  You can do this for each of the declared dependencies.